# Latest Spring Boot [2.5.0] webclient bug?

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

I have recently upgraded my project to the latest version of spring-boot 2.5.0 and got going with refactoring a ton of deprecated code. I noticed that `awaitExchange()` has now been deprecated and should be replaced with `awaitExchange{it}`

However, as soon as I replaced one with the other it appears I can no longer extract the body from the **ClientResponse** object by `response.awaitBody()` in a different class and keep getting `No value received via onNext for awaitSingle`. Is such behaviour by design?
Is there any other way to actually get hold of the body without having to use `
`awaitExchange{ it.awaitBody() }` in the class that makes the webservice call?

Answer (score 1):

Since you did not show your code its hard to say what is the issue. But you can use `WebClient` in following ways

```
val client = WebClient.create()

val data: MultiValueMap<String, String> = LinkedMultiValueMap()
data["username"] = "johndoe"
data["target_site"] = "aloha"

client.create()
      .post()
      .uri("some uri")
      .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
      .body(BodyInserters.fromFormData(data))
      .retrieve()
      .awaitBodyOrNull<String>() ?: throw Exception("Received null response")
```

Another way to do is

```
val response = client.get()
                     .uri("some uri")
                     .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                     .retrieve()
                     .toEntity(String::class.java)
                     .awaitSingle()

if (!response.statusCode.is2xxSuccessful) {

    throw Exception("Received ${response.statusCodeValue} response.")
}
```